# PARALLELPERIOD error in MDX Query

Tags: ssas, grouping, mdx

I have used the below mentioned query for a **PARALLAELPERIOD**

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [MEASURES].[DATO AR] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Dato] = 'AT'
     ,NULL
     ,[Measures].[Dato]
    ) 
  MEMBER [MEASURES].[Indice] AS 
    IIF
    (
      ([Tempo].[Mese Anno].[Dic-2011],[Measures].[Dato]) = 0
     ,null
     ,
        [Measures].[DATO AR] / ([Tempo].[Mese Anno].[Dic-2011],[Measures].[Dato])
      * 100
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [MEASURES].[DATO AR]
     ,[MEASURES].[Indice]
    } ON 0
 ,ParallelPeriod
  (
    [Tempo].[Mese Anno].CurrentMember.UniqueName
   ,3
   ,Filter
    (
      Order
      (
        NonEmpty([Tempo].[Periodo].[Mese Anno])
       ,[Tempo].[Periodo].CurrentMember.MemberValue
       ,Bdesc
      )
     ,Instr
      (
        [Tempo].[Periodo].[Mese Anno].CurrentMember.Name
       ,'Dic'
      )
    )
  ) ON 1
FROM AGRO;
```

I am getting an error as below:

```
The PARALLELPERIOD function expects a member expression for the 3 argument. A tuple set expression was used.
```

Below image show the dimension being used:

[image]

The data available is until April 2016. I want to get only the last three December value, i.e., Dic-2015, Dic-2014 and Dic-2013

And when we reach Decmeber 2016, it should be Dic-2016, Dic-2015 and Dic-2014.

Can someone suggest the change in the query ,mentioned above.

Comment: What is your actual question? The syntac for `ParallelPeriod` is incorrect is wrong, that is one thing. But what exactly are you trying to achieve? `I want to get only the last three December value, i.e., Dic-2015, Dic-2014 and Dic-2013` - are you trying to filter in only december data??

Comment: yes... trying to filter only December Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AdvWrks I can do this - using your nifty little Filter idea:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,Filter
  (
    [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
   ,Instr
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name
     ,'December'
    )
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This returns the set of every December

[image]

So we can now just use Tail to get the last 3 of them:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,Tail
  (
    Filter
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
     ,Instr
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name
       ,'December'
      )
    )
   ,3
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The above returns this:

[image]

If I only want the last 3 *with data* best to use the `NonEmpty` function:

```
SELECT 
  {} ON 0
 ,Tail
  (
    Filter
    (
      NonEmpty([Date].[Calendar].[Month])
     ,Instr
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name
       ,'December'
      )
    )
   ,3
  ) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

This changes the 3 Decembers to the following:

[image]

To make things more readable I prefer this sort of logic in a `WITH` clause.

Comment: I kind of used the same thing... but not with TAIL, rather than I used a TOPCOUNT as I was using an ORDER as well

Comment: And yes, this TAIL thing also works for me... Thanks... Marking it as my valid answer

Comment: @YousufSultan glad this was some help